# Enabling permalink pages in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" Take me to another page </a>` to take the user to a permalink page.

However, when I do, it is saying `No input file specified.`

I have the following files in theme folder:

```
footer.php
functions.php
header.php
style.css
index.php
```

How come this is not working — am I missing another php template file?

Comment: That sounds more like an error the web server would return. Are your rewrite mods enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Your template files have to be in a directory under /wp-content/thmes/your-theme/. After you inserted them into the theme dir you have to activate your theme in the wordpress administration.

You need also at least a index.php File. That's the file where you place the functions for your content. In the index.php your include the header.php and footer.php with the Wordpress functions get_header() and get_footer().

I think you should better read the Documentations:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: Ah apologies! I have indeed got the files within the correct template folder and with an `index.php`. I didn't explain it well enough— I'll edit that now.

Comment: I think it's server: http://herbert-theme.info/ . If you click any of the images, they would ideally take you to a permalink page. But I'm not sure how to implement that

Comment: Is the URL http://herbert-theme.info/this-is-the-title/ inserted with your the_permalink() or have you set it manually?

Comment: Inserted with permalink from the loop: <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">

Comment: Then it's definetly a server problem. Can you post the contents of your .htaccess file?

Comment: I can't post it in the comments box, far too long. Is there something I should look at for?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fuchskit/nuhYJ/ This is how it should look like. Are there any differences with yours?

Comment: Ah. My .htaccess file (within the theme root) is much longer. Here is the contents: http://jsfiddle.net/nuhYJ/1/

Comment: Try disabling your .htaccess (add something before the point like text.htaccess) and insert the one I sent you into the wordpress root.

Comment: Ah, just disabling the .htaccess in the theme root seemed to work. Should there not be a .htaccess in the theme root? :)

Comment: Never heard of. There should only be the one in the wordpress root when the permalinks are enabled.

Comment: Ah, you're correct. That is what I was disabling. I've disabled that main `.htaccess` and the WordPress site works fine with permalinks. That can't be good?!